# RubyMine - Debug Rails App - Unicorn Server

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

i am trying to debug rails app - unicorn server.

I've tried following:

1) I tried to start the server on localhost (externally, not with RubyMine) and set some break points. I can see my server when trying to "attach to process". It can attach to process but when i call some REST WebService it won't stop on this method in controller.

2) I tried to run the server from Debugger in RubyMine, the server starts, but when i call some REST WebService it won't stop on this method in controller.

How to debug the Rails App on Mac OS (localhost, unicorn)?

The Rails App ist only API. I want to debug my api calls.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:
- i was using pow and it was redirecting to some url and not directly to localhost:3000. Once i converted the requests to use localhost:3000 instead of pow URL xxx.something.test debugger fired up.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have rubymine but this worked for me:

install "pry": https://github.com/pry/pry

start unicorn on your local env:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb
```

make sure you're listening to a valid port (in your confic/unicorn.rb):

```
listen 3000
```

add

```
binding.pry
```

in your code wherever you want a breakpoint

go to:

```
0.0.0.0:3000
```